# How to display mirror reflection in viewport?

Tags: materials

How can I display the amount of reflection an object has in the viewport?

Comment: You can't, unless you use rendered shading

Comment: maybe matcap , but it use it's own lights

Comment: Matcap does show glossines, but of course not in any way related to the material of the model.

Comment: Well.. Some matcaps can look reflective, but it's really just mapping a static image to the surface of the model. It won't pay any attention to the material or surrounding environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The viewport has several ways of displaying your scene.

*During modelling* you might use Solid Shading, Material Shading,  Wireframe, or even GLSL (matcap) shading can be useful.

*Reflectivity* can only be seen (June 2015) in Rendered Viewport mode, this works for Cycles and Blender Internal engines, these options can give you a quick approximation of what the final render will look like.

[image]